# What is the meaning of the following sentence

Tags: meaning

What does "Lionel Messi brace gets Barcelona off to winning start" mean?

Comment: What part of the sentence don't you understand?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of "brace" and "get off " here in this sentence

Comment: I'm flagging as off-topic (no research). Mahnaz, our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "questions about the following topics ... are out of scope for this site. # *The meaning of words, or synonyms for words, unless you have first looked them up in a dictionary or thesaurus*." If that doesn't help, [edit] your question to tell us what you found and where the confusion remains. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: FWIW: Look up "brace" in a dictionary - presumably Messi scored at least 2 goals. See the first definition of [get off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'brace' (among other meanings) [has an old English meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brace) of "two things of the same type, especially two wild birds that have been killed for sport or food". It has passed into football slang meaning "two goals" (especially in headlines where space is important and "brace" is shorter than "two goals".

"off to a winning start" means that the start of some event, especially a competition, is "winning". Other adjectives work just as well: "The evening got off to a dull start with a  reading of a long poem", "The candidate got his campaign off to a terrible start by insulting all voters".